# UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: the cornerRadius value is not consistent

Tags: ios, uikit, calayer, round-rect

I want to draw a round rect in an CALayer using [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: cornerRadius:], when setting up the rect's cornerRadius, I found that it is not consistent from 0 to maximum radius(about half of the layer's bound). The value jumped at about 1/3 of maximum radius which is quite confusing. After some research, I found probably it's a bug of iOS7 style of UIBezierPath drawing a round rect. [PaintCode's research on that](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/blogpost/code-for-ios-7-rounded-rectangles). So my question is how to draw an old style of perfect round rect with consistent cornerRadius value change?

Comment: Please review [ask]. You need to post the code you've written, as well as images showing the issue.

Comment: Also ... do you want a `CALayer` with rounded corners? Or, do you want to create a Bezier Path with rounded corners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's clearly an Apple bug here. When we draw a shape layer with this path:

```
UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 50, y: 20, width: 208, height: 50), cornerRadius: 20).cgPath
```

This is what we get:

[image]

That's just not right. The height is 50, the corner radius is 20, so there should be an obvious flat part at the end, 10 points in height. Where did it go? Instead, Apple has *increased the radius* from the radius you asked for, and has just round-capped the entire ends of the rectangle. It ought to look more like this:

[image]

That's what both DonMag and I are trying to fix.

It will be useful to have on hand a replacement rounded rect method on UIBezierBath that works as expected. We can write DonMag's code much more neatly by calling `addArc(tangent1End:...)`; most people have never heard of this wonderful method, but it was made for exactly this sort of job. I'll also take the opportunity to establish some nice names for the corners of a CGRect:

```
extension CGRect {
    var topRight: CGPoint { CGPoint(x: maxX, y: minY) }
    var topLeft: CGPoint { CGPoint(x: minX, y: minY) }
    var bottomRight: CGPoint { CGPoint(x: maxX, y: maxY) }
    var bottomLeft: CGPoint { CGPoint(x: minX, y: maxY) }
}

extension UIBezierPath {
    static func roundedRect(rect: CGRect, cornerRadius: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        let start = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY)
        path.move(to: start)
        path.addArc(tangent1End: rect.topRight, tangent2End: rect.bottomRight, radius: cornerRadius)
        path.addArc(tangent1End: rect.bottomRight, tangent2End: rect.bottomLeft, radius: cornerRadius)
        path.addArc(tangent1End: rect.bottomLeft, tangent2End: rect.topLeft, radius: cornerRadius)
        path.addArc(tangent1End: rect.topLeft, tangent2End: start, radius: cornerRadius)
        return UIBezierPath(cgPath: path)
    }
}
```

Now simply call `UIBezierPath.roundedRect(rect:cornerRadius)` instead of the buggy `UIBezierPath(roundedRect:cornerRadius)`, and the problem is solved.

If you want to go further, we can include a parameter allowing us to specify what corners to round:

```
extension UIBezierPath {
    static func roundedRect(
        rect: CGRect,
        corners: UIRectCorner = .allCorners,
        cornerRadius: CGFloat
    ) -> UIBezierPath {
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        let start = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY)
        path.move(to: start)
        if corners.contains(.topRight) {
            path.addArc(tangent1End: rect.topRight, tangent2End: rect.bottomRight, radius: cornerRadius)
        } else {
            path.addLine(to: rect.topRight)
        }
        if corners.contains(.bottomRight) {
            path.addArc(tangent1End: rect.bottomRight, tangent2End: rect.bottomLeft, radius: cornerRadius)
        } else {
            path.addLine(to: rect.bottomRight)
        }
        if corners.contains(.bottomLeft) {
            path.addArc(tangent1End: rect.bottomLeft, tangent2End: rect.topLeft, radius: cornerRadius)
        } else {
            path.addLine(to: rect.bottomLeft)
        }
        if corners.contains(.topLeft) {
            path.addArc(tangent1End: rect.topLeft, tangent2End: start, radius: cornerRadius)
        } else {
            path.addLine(to: rect.topLeft)
        }
        return UIBezierPath(cgPath: path)
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Okay, but it doesn't look right! That's because I'm drawing with the `.circular` style of rounded corner, but Apple draws with the `.continuous` style. Let's fix that by emulating the `.continuous` style:

```
extension CGRect {
    var topRight: CGPoint { CGPoint(x: maxX, y: minY) }
    var topLeft: CGPoint { CGPoint(x: minX, y: minY) }
    var bottomRight: CGPoint { CGPoint(x: maxX, y: maxY) }
    var bottomLeft: CGPoint { CGPoint(x: minX, y: maxY) }
}

extension CGPoint {
    func offset(x xOffset: CGFloat, y yOffset: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
        CGPoint(x: x + xOffset, y: y + yOffset)
    }
}

extension UIBezierPath {
    static func roundedRect(
        rect: CGRect,
        corners: UIRectCorner = .allCorners,
        cornerRadius: CGFloat
    ) -> UIBezierPath {
        let tweak = 1.2 // could experiment with this
        let offset = cornerRadius * tweak
        if rect.height > 2 * offset { // less than that, my algorithm starts to break down — but theirs works!
            let path = CGMutablePath()
            let start = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY)
            path.move(to: start)
            if corners.contains(.topRight) {
                path.addLine(to: rect.topRight.offset(x: -offset, y: 0))
                path.addQuadCurve(to: rect.topRight.offset(x: 0, y: offset), control: rect.topRight)
            } else {
                path.addLine(to: rect.topRight)
            }
            if corners.contains(.bottomRight) {
                path.addLine(to: rect.bottomRight.offset(x: 0, y: -offset))
                path.addQuadCurve(to: rect.bottomRight.offset(x: -offset, y: 0), control: rect.bottomRight)
            } else {
                path.addLine(to: rect.bottomRight)
            }
            if corners.contains(.bottomLeft) {
                path.addLine(to: rect.bottomLeft.offset(x: offset, y: 0))
                path.addQuadCurve(to: rect.bottomLeft.offset(x: -0, y: -offset), control: rect.bottomLeft)
            } else {
                path.addLine(to: rect.bottomLeft)
            }
            if corners.contains(.topLeft) {
                path.addLine(to: rect.topLeft.offset(x: 0, y: offset))
                path.addQuadCurve(to: rect.topLeft.offset(x: offset, y: 0), control: rect.topLeft)
            } else {
                path.addLine(to: rect.topLeft)
            }
            return UIBezierPath(cgPath: path)
        }
        return UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: cornerRadius, height: cornerRadius))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Took a look at the PaintCode link you posted (although, it's much easier to answer questions here that explain the issue without having to go read an article somewhere else)...

Yes, it appears `UIBezierPath(roundedRect: ...)` is still buggy when the radius is greater than - as you noted - roughly 1/3 of 1/2 of the rect dimension.

To create a rounded rect path "manually," we can do this (using the rect dimensions and corner radius from that link):

```
let r: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150.0, height: 153.0)
let cornerRad: CGFloat = 50.0

// center points for the corner arcs
let ptCTR: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: r.maxX - cornerRad, y: r.minY + cornerRad)
let ptCBR: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: r.maxX - cornerRad, y: r.maxY - cornerRad)
let ptCBL: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: r.minX + cornerRad, y: r.maxY - cornerRad)
let ptCTL: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: r.minX + cornerRad, y: r.minY + cornerRad)
    
let bez: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    
// Top-Right corner
bez.addArc(withCenter: ptCTR, radius: cornerRad, startAngle: .pi * 1.5, endAngle: .pi * 0.0, clockwise: true)
    
// Bottom-Right corner
bez.addArc(withCenter: ptCBR, radius: cornerRad, startAngle: .pi * 0.0, endAngle: .pi * 0.5, clockwise: true)
    
// Bottom-Left corner
bez.addArc(withCenter: ptCBL, radius: cornerRad, startAngle: .pi * 0.5, endAngle: .pi * 1.0, clockwise: true)
    
// Top-Left corner
bez.addArc(withCenter: ptCTL, radius: cornerRad, startAngle: .pi * 1.0, endAngle: .pi * 1.5, clockwise: true)
    
// close the path
bez.close()
```

Comment: Code could be considerably cleaned up. See my answer, which calls `addArc(tangent1End:...)`.

Comment: @matt - too true :)

Comment: Okay, bad news; neither of us is right. They don't do their corner rounding with simple semicircles. I'm working on it...

Comment: Okay, now I've got it.