# UIBezierPath(roundedRect:cornerRadius:) creates a fully rounded object

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uibezierpath

I'm trying to create layer with rounded corners using `UIBezierPath(roundedRect:cornerRadius:)`. For example, I have `rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 208, height: 64)` and `cornerRadius = 24`. When I use `UIBezierPath` it creates fully rounded corners object, but if I try to set cornerRadius directly to CALayer.cornerRadius everything is fine. In Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624356-init) says about a radius of half the height or width, but my radius is less than half the height or width.

Code with BezierPath:

```
private lazy var borderLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.lineWidth = 1
    layer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    layer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    layer.masksToBounds = true
    return layer
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .black
    borderLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 308, height: 100)
    borderLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 208, height: 64), cornerRadius: 24).cgPath
    view.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
```

Result Image with UIBezierPath: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiQVE.png

Result Image with directly set cornerRadius to CALayer (`borderLayer.cornerRadius = 24`): https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t5O9.png

Comment: Yes, it's a known bug. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74623415/uibezierpath-bezierpathwithroundedrect-the-cornerradius-value-is-not-consistent. Simple solution: don't call `roundedRect:cornerRadius:`. Just draw the corner arcs yourself. It's easy enough to do.

Comment: I've added what I think is a nicer answer to that question.