# How to add border color only to specific sides with corner radius in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hello I have a request to create a UIView with cornerRadius only on topLeft and topRight and add borderColor only at left, right and top

Searching for an answer I tried some solutions but the best I've got is this

[image]

As you can see I have the sides I want with borders but they're not rounded

Here is what I tried:

```
let firstView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 60, width: 100, height: 100))
firstView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
firstView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
firstView.backgroundColor = .white
firstView.borders(for: [.top, .left, .right])
```

This is the code I used searching SO

```
extension UIView {
func borders(for edges:[UIRectEdge], width:CGFloat = 1, color: UIColor = .black) {

    if edges.contains(.all) {
        layer.borderWidth = width
        layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
    } else {
        let allSpecificBorders:[UIRectEdge] = [.top, .bottom, .left, .right]

        for edge in allSpecificBorders {
            if let v = viewWithTag(Int(edge.rawValue)) {
                v.removeFromSuperview()
            }

            if edges.contains(edge) {
                let v = UIView()
                v.tag = Int(edge.rawValue)
                v.backgroundColor = color
                v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                addSubview(v)

                var horizontalVisualFormat = "H:"
                var verticalVisualFormat = "V:"

                switch edge {
                case UIRectEdge.bottom:
                    horizontalVisualFormat += "|-(0)-[v]-(0)-|"
                    verticalVisualFormat += "[v(\(width))]-(0)-|"
                case UIRectEdge.top:
                    horizontalVisualFormat += "|-(0)-[v]-(0)-|"
                    verticalVisualFormat += "|-(0)-[v(\(width))]"
                case UIRectEdge.left:
                    horizontalVisualFormat += "|-(0)-[v(\(width))]"
                    verticalVisualFormat += "|-(0)-[v]-(0)-|"
                case UIRectEdge.right:
                    horizontalVisualFormat += "[v(\(width))]-(0)-|"
                    verticalVisualFormat += "|-(0)-[v]-(0)-|"
                default:
                    break
                }

                self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: horizontalVisualFormat, options: .directionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["v": v]))
                self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: verticalVisualFormat, options: .directionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["v": v]))
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

If I add cornerRadius to `v` UIView the result is this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You would have to draw the border with a bezier path. And you would also mask the view to round the corners yourself, to match it.

Comment: Based on your image... you want border on left/top/right (but not bottom) and you want rounded corners on top only?

Comment: @DonMag yes exactly

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75592757/341994 for code you can modify.

Comment: @matt I'm thinking now you mention bezier path wouldn't be easier to add border width that would add borders to the whole view and then just draw a line at the side I don't want? (A little more specific way for sure)

Comment: I have absolutely used tricks like overlapping views to do this sort of thing in the past. Still, it is better all around to learn to draw the view / shape that you want, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would strongly suggest using a custom `UIView` subclass, rather than a `UIView` **extension**. Many advantages.

So, simple example...

First, we'll use Matt's `CGRect` extension (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75592757/341994)) to make things a bit easier:

```
extension CGRect {
    var topRight: CGPoint { CGPoint(x: maxX, y: minY) }
    var topLeft: CGPoint { CGPoint(x: minX, y: minY) }
    var bottomRight: CGPoint { CGPoint(x: maxX, y: maxY) }
    var bottomLeft: CGPoint { CGPoint(x: minX, y: maxY) }
}
```

then, a `UIView` subclass that does all the work:

```
class MyCustomView: UIView {
    
    // this allows us to use the "base" layer as a shape layer
    //  instead of adding a sublayer
    lazy var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = self.layer as! CAShapeLayer
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAShapeLayer.self
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        shapeLayer.fillColor = nil
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        let radius: CGFloat = 10.0
        
        let pth = CGMutablePath()
        
        // start at bottom-left corner
        pth.move(to: bounds.bottomLeft)
        // rounded top-left corner
        pth.addArc(tangent1End: bounds.topLeft, tangent2End: bounds.topRight, radius: radius)
        // rounded top-right corner
        pth.addArc(tangent1End: bounds.topRight, tangent2End: bounds.bottomRight, radius: radius)
        // line to bottom-right corner
        pth.addLine(to: bounds.bottomRight)

        shapeLayer.path = pth
        
        // round top corners of view (self)
        shapeLayer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
        shapeLayer.cornerRadius = radius
    }
    
}
```

and an example view controller showing it "in action":

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let testView = MyCustomView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemCyan
        
        testView.backgroundColor = .white
        
        testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(testView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            testView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            testView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0),
            testView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0),
            testView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
        ])
        
    }
    
}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer I will try it and I will test Fabio's answer too and I will accept which will fit to my scenario better

Comment: If i want this output for UITableViewCell then is it working ?

Comment: @Birju - not sure what you are asking... Of course, it will "work" in a `UITableViewCell`. Add this `MyCustomView` as a subview of your cell's contentView, and constrain all four sides... see if the result is what you want.

Comment: @DonMag Thanks for reply. I have one concern that if i use this subclass for UITableViewCell then will it create multiple time ? Because when user scroll tableview everytime layoutsubview method will be call and everytime layer will add.

Comment: @Birju - it's never *creating and adding* a new layer... it initializes the "base layer" as a `CAShapeLayer`. So no worries about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with autolayout, take a look to this example:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {

let yourView = UIView()
let bgView = UIView()

let border: CGFloat = 2 // your border width

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    
    // your background view --> border color
    bgView.backgroundColor = .black
    bgView.clipsToBounds = true
    bgView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    bgView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
    bgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    yourView.backgroundColor = .white
    yourView.clipsToBounds = true
    yourView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    yourView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
    yourView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    view.addSubview(bgView)
    bgView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    bgView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    bgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    bgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    
    bgView.addSubview(yourView)
    yourView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgView.topAnchor, constant: border).isActive = true
    yourView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgView.leadingAnchor, constant: border).isActive = true
    yourView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgView.trailingAnchor, constant: -border).isActive = true
    yourView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
  }
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer I tried and is working I will test DonMag's answer too and I will accept which will fit to my scenario better

Comment: How to round four corners in this way?

Answer (score 0):

For customizing `border corners` you can use following custom class.

```
import UIKit

class CustomBorderView: UIView {
    
    private var corners : UIRectCorner = .allCorners
    private var radius : CGFloat = 6.0
    private var borderColor : UIColor = UIColor.black
    private var borderLineWidth : CGFloat = 1.0
    
    lazy private var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer? = self.layer as? CAShapeLayer
    
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAShapeLayer.self
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
     // If view's background color is set to clear and you want to pass touches to the views underneath then add following function.
    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        for subview in subviews {
            if !subview.isHidden && subview.isUserInteractionEnabled && subview.point(inside: convert(point, to: subview), with: event) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    func commonInit() {
        shapeLayer?.fillColor = nil
        shapeLayer?.strokeColor = borderColor.cgColor
        shapeLayer?.lineWidth = borderLineWidth
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        apply()
    }

    override func setNeedsDisplay() {
        super.setNeedsDisplay()
        apply()
    }
    
    func update(corners : UIRectCorner = .allCorners, radius : CGFloat = 6.0, borderLineWidth : CGFloat = 1.0, borderColor : UIColor = UIColor.black) {
        self.corners = corners
        self.radius = radius
        self.borderLineWidth = borderLineWidth
        self.borderColor = borderColor
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
    func updateMaskCorners(corners : UIRectCorner = .allCorners) {
        self.corners = corners
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
    func updateRadius(radius : CGFloat) {
        self.radius = radius
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
    func updateBorderLineWidth(width : CGFloat) {
        self.borderLineWidth = width
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
    func updateBorderColor(color : UIColor) {
        self.borderColor = color
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
    private func apply() {
        shapeLayer?.fillColor = nil
        shapeLayer?.strokeColor = borderColor.cgColor
        shapeLayer?.lineWidth = borderLineWidth
        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners:corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        bezierPath.lineWidth = borderLineWidth
        shapeLayer?.path = bezierPath.cgPath
    }
    
}
```

For usage:

```
let borderView = CustomBorderView()
borderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
borderView.backgroundColor = .clear // any color if you want
yourView.addSubview(borderView)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
  borderView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: yourView.leadingAnchor),
  borderView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: yourView.topAnchor),
  borderView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: yourView.bottomAnchor),
  borderView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: yourView.trailingAnchor)
])

borderView.setNeedsDisplay()
```