# UIBezierPath roundedRect has strange gaps

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, core-graphics

I need to draw a rounded rect. However, at very special corner radius values (between 34 to 37), it causes very strange bugs like the image below. Can someone explain to me why it happened?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        drawView()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .red
    }

    func drawView() {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 100)
        let borderWidth = 10.0
        let cornerRadius = 34.0
        
        
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        layer.lineWidth = borderWidth
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
        
        
        layer.path = path.cgPath
        
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Using CGMutablePath can resolve above problems as well as radius = 0

Comment: Do not give a solution as part of the question. If you have an answer to the question, put it in the Answer field.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that a rounded rectangle is implemented by joining some curves together and the artifact that you are seeing is caused by the `lineJoin` property of the layer.

Setting `lineJoin` to `.round` fixes it for me:

```
layer.lineJoin = .round
```

[image]

Comment: I just found the same solution. Very weird because if you change the line width slightly, the problem goes away even if you don't set the `lineJoin`.

Comment: @HangarRash I think it is just some rendering artifact or some bug in CoreAnimation. I don't know enough about computer graphics, or how CoreAnimation is implemented, to explain in detail though.

Comment: This have problem with radius =0 , it still make a rounded rect.
I'm checking radius > 0 .round : .miter

Comment: @TrungPhan Yeah, but didn't you want a rounded rectangle in the first place? So what happens at radius = 0 doesn't matter, does it?

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks. Actually I need draw a rectangle, user can set the size, border width, border radius. This is a special bug I have.

Comment: @TrungPhan I see. Well then `radius > 0 .round : .miter` should work. I think it would use 4 straight lines and 4 arcs joined together when radius > 0, and only 4 straight lines if radius is 0.

Comment: @Sweeper use CGMutablePath can resolve all of above problem, including radius = 0

Comment: @TrungPhan See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75592757/341994 for how to draw a rounded rect path.

Answer (score 0):

Using 2 bezierpath and fill with color instead of using single path with stroke.

The problem is CALayer using multiple path to create a border, cause overlap between the path then it mixed with fill rule .evenOdd cause weird behavior.
This also make impossible to create a perfect circle.

This article explained why is it happened.

https://www.paintcodeapp.com/blogpost/code-for-ios-7-rounded-rectangles

Thanks Zalo iOS VietNam team to help me understand this.

My solution to avoid overlap by using 2 separated paths and fill color between them.

The another way to fix is using CGMutablePath.

```
 func draw() {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 30, y: 50, width: 200, height: 100)
        let boderWidth: CGFloat = 5
        let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 5
        
        
        
        let outterPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: cornerRadius, height: cornerRadius))
        
        let innerRect = CGRect(x: rect.minX + boderWidth, y: rect.minY + boderWidth, width: rect.width - boderWidth * 2, height: rect.height - boderWidth * 2)
        let innerPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: innerRect, byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: cornerRadius, height: cornerRadius))
        
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.append(outterPath)
        path.append(innerPath)
        
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        layer.fillRule = .evenOdd
        layer.path = path.cgPath
        
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    }
```